# Transform list to list of tuples

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

This is my current code for my sign up/login program and I am having a problem with it:

```py
info = []
n = 0
true = "true"

while true == "true":
    command = input("What would you like to do?\nLogin or Signup? ")
    if "ogin" in command:
        loginusername = input("\nWhat is your username? ")
        loginpassword = input("What is your password? ")
        if (loginusername and loginpassword) in info:
            print("\nYou have logged in!\n")           
        else:
            print("\nYou have not signed up!\n")
    if "ignup" in command:
        usernameinput = input("\nWhat do you want your username to be? ")
        info.insert(n, usernameinput)
        usernameinput = "false"
        passwordinput = input("\nWhat do you want your password to be? ")
        info.insert(n, passwordinput)
        passwordinput = "false"
        print("\n\nYou have successfully signed up!")
        n += 1
```

I have tried alsorts but the input will not be recorded as I want it to be. I would like it to be recorded like this as an example:

```py
info == [("username1", "password1")]
```

Is there a way I can record it like that because at the moment, the code records the data like this:

```py
info == ["username1", "password1"]
```

Comment: sure, but what is the user supposed to put in? the name and the password?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] RIght now I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TomGolledge: Is the edited version also complying with what you would like to achieve? It looks like this is what you need - transformation from one data structure to the other.

Comment: You should have tried some code first and then if not successful,  posted your best failing attempt.  On my third attempt, in 1 minute, I came up with `list((tuple(ui),))`, which matches your example.  But I like timgeb's answer better.  And I wonder why other code should need the transformation.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear, I wanted to create a signup system that allows the user to enter a username and password into the system, the program will then ask them if they want to login and I want it to be able to take the username and password they signed up with and compare it to the input when they login.

Comment: I will try to get the code I attempted and paste it here. I couldn't access the code at the time since my main hard drive, with the code on, is currently getting repaired

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you prompt the user twice, for the username and the password. Example:

```
uname = input('enter username: ')
pw = input('enter password: ')
result = [(uname, pw)] # this is the result you requested
print(result)
```

Demo:

```
$ python3 inputdemo.py 
enter username: bob
enter password: pw      
[('bob', 'pw')]
```

Edit: To transform already gathered data, you can do also the following:

```py
user, password = user_input
result = [(user, password)]
```

or the following:

```py
result = [tuple(user_input)]
```

(`user_input` will be converted from `list` to `tuple`)